# ssh remote command parsing gone wrong

Tags: ssh, bash

I am trying to execute a single remote command via ssh for debugging setup. This does not execute the correct command (I cannot see the output but it seems the PID is missing to gdbserver):

```
ssh -t admin@myhost.com "ps -A | grep myprocess | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} gdbserver --attach 0.0.0.0:52159 {}"
```

while doing it local works:

```
ps -A | grep myprocess | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} sudo gdbserver --attach 0.0.0.0:52159 {}
```

Where does it go wrong in the parsing?

Comment: You're missing the `awk '{print $1}'` from the first command.

Comment: oh typo in question, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this out myself and debugged by inserting an echo command:

```
ssh -t admin@myhost.com "ps -A | grep rsyslogd | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{} echo gdbserver --attach 0.0.0.0:52159 {}"
```

The last part that should have been just the PID was instead:

```
1209 ?        00:00:05 rsyslogd
```

My guess is that the $ sign in the awk was being interpreted by bash somewhere and turned into an empty string, so the awk command was just `{print}`.

Adding a backslash before the $ fixed it and produced a final command that includes just the PID.

```
ssh -t admin@myhost.com "ps -A | grep rsyslogd | awk '{print \$1}' | xargs -I{} echo gdbserver --attach 0.0.0.0:52159 {}"
```